# Does pessimistic locking take values from hibernate first level cache

Tags: hibernate, grails

This method is called on multiple sessions upon receiving a request on an external service. It is setup in a way that it will lock one MyEntity row at time and commit it right away. In that way, we expect it to always have the accurate value and make sure that a row is modified one at a time.

We are using Grails, so the syntax is in Groovy.

```
process() {
  list.each {
    MyEntity.withNewTransaction { //REQUIRES_NEW transaction propagation
      def myEntity = MyEntity.lock(list.getMyEntityId)
      //edit myEntity then save it
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is, we are encountering stale object errors. It says the the entity is already modified despite fetching it with pessimistic locking. My guess is the entity is being fetched on the hibernate first level cache.

Adding a refresh right after each pessimistic query on MyEntity fixes it. My understanding is this should not be necessary, since pessimistic locking should do a "for update" to the db everytime, even if it is already queried before in the same session but different transaction. Is that correct?

BTW, I'm using Postgres Sql. And did not modify the isolation level.

Comment: The L1 Cache is session-bound and so if you're absolutely sure your code isn't sharing sessions, then the L1 Cache would not be the reason.

Comment: @Naros Just confirming, if I'm using one session, and fetching entities via pessimisitc lock on separate transactions, L1 cache would still be used for the succeeding queries?